# Is still possible to play Just Dance 2015 with Android app?

Tags: just-dance-2015

I've purchased a used copy of *Just Dance 2015* for my niece to see if the game is suitable for her, in order to eventually get a newer version for Christmas.

As far as I know, it's possible to play Just Dance using an Android app called [Just Dance Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubisoft.dance.justdance2015companion&hl=en) but it appears that now it only supports 2016-2020 versions of the game.
The 2015 version was called [Just Dance 2015 Motion Controller](https://www.ign.com/articles/2014/10/29/just-dance-2015-motion-controller-app-now-available) but I can't find it anywhere. Every link redirects me to the newer app.

Is the 2015 version no more supported by the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Just Dance wikia](https://justdance.fandom.com/wiki/Just_Dance_Controller#Trivia):

> In the Just Dance 2019 version (Version 5.0.0) of the app, compatibility with Just Dance 2015 was removed.
>   This is due to the shutdown announcement of the online servers for Just Dance 2015 on November 19, 2018.